# цифры после E

Tags: java

как определить цифры после E ?
 есть например число 1.234e27 хочу записать в виде 1.234 * 10^27
как правильно получить эту степень, можно конечно перевести число в строку и парсить, но как то не красиво...

Comment: можно перевести в строку, а потом сделать замену 'e' на ' * 10 ^ ' и всех делов то.

Comment: А десятичный логарифм сосчитать совсем не судьба?

Comment: @alexlz: там на самом деле хитрее, из-за ненормализованных значений.

Comment: @VladD чуток пояснее можно? Непонятно, что Вы имеете в виду. Результат java.lang.Math.log10 зависит от нормализации?

Единственная проблема -- не пытаться брать логарифм нуля и отрицательных значениий, т.е. `floor(log10(abs(x)))`

Comment: @alexlz: я имел в виду вот этих зверей: [subnormal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number). Те, у которых мантисса не начинается с 1. Стоп, вы правы, логарифм-то всё равно будет такой как надо. Туплю, конец дня :)

Comment: @VladD, всё равно не понял. Логарифм от них считается или нет? Если считается, то его битовое представление меня волновать не должно. (hint:  static double  log10(double a) -- диапазон значений с количеством бит, отведённых на порядок вроде не связан)

Comment: @alexlz: пока вы читали комментарий, я его обновил :) Вы правы, логарифм от внутренних подробностей устройства представления чисел по стандарту IEEE 754 не зависит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот вам [код Джона Скита](https://stackoverflow.com/a/390072/276994):

```
// Translate the double into sign, exponent and mantissa.
long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d);
// Note that the shift is sign-extended, hence the test against -1 not 1
bool negative = (bits < 0);
int exponent = (int) ((bits >> 52) & 0x7ffL);
long mantissa = bits & 0xfffffffffffffL;

// Subnormal numbers; exponent is effectively one higher,
// but there's no extra normalisation bit in the mantissa
if (exponent==0)
{
    exponent++;
}
// Normal numbers; leave exponent as it is but add extra
// bit to the front of the mantissa
else
{
    mantissa = mantissa | (1L<<52);
}

// Bias the exponent. It's actually biased by 1023, but we're
// treating the mantissa as m.0 rather than 0.m, so we need
// to subtract another 52 from it.
exponent -= 1075;

if (mantissa == 0) 
{
    return "0";
}

/* Normalize */
while((mantissa & 1) == 0) 
{    /*  i.e., Mantissa is even */
    mantissa >>= 1;
    exponent++;
}
```

Он на C#, но перевести на Java несложно :) (Единственное отличие -- [Double.doubleToRawLongBits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits%28double%29) вместо `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits`.)